# Automatically extract original dataset from a line plot image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

Given a line plot image (bitmap, png, etc) form, I'm looking to extract the set of original datapoints without any user input, as shown in the below image:

[image: example line plot]

The outcome should be something like below:

```
`-  A,B,C
x1: 1,2,3
x2: 2,4,9
x3: 3,8,27
x4: 4,16,23
x5: 5,13,18
x6: 6,18,21
x7: 7,19,23`
```

Solutions like [webplotdigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) require user input which isn't what I'm looking for.  [scatteract](https://github.com/bloomberg/scatteract) is very close but I don't think it works on using line plots.

Can anybody point me to papers or open source projects on this?

Thanks in advance.